# How to get sleuth http headers for reactor netty client request via breakpoint?

Tags: spring, netty, project-reactor, spring-cloud-sleuth, reactor-netty

Given a client request of the form

```
return webClient.get()  
    .uri(customersUrl + id)  
    .retrieve()  
    .bodyToMono(Customer.class)
    .block();
```

I would like to have a scriptable breakpoint at some place in the outgoing request where I can obtain the http headers, including any span id headers added by sleuth (and before any SSL encryption takes place). Preferably this breakpoint should be somewhere on the same thread as the above request - if the breakpoint is on the async thread that actually does the socket write, there is a danger that the next breakpoint hit will be that initiated by another client request.

There is a real reason why I need to use breakpoints like this so I can't do anything that requires modifying the code.

I have found places on the async thread where the http headers are available - e.g. in `reactor/netty/http/HttpOperations.then` but I am struggling to find a similar place on the original client thread. I'm hoping this isn't all deferred via lambdas or something until the async thread consumes the subscription.